# Unexpected response code 503 (Android Studio)

Tags: php, android, error-handling, server, android-volley

i have an android app and i have created API's in php, and i have uploaded all API's on hostinger.com 
What my app is doing for example i have to login into app my android code is this:

```
String register_url="http://iot2k19.hostingerapp.com/do_login.php";
```

what this does? it let my app to use do_login.php and do_login.php is present in file manager of hostinger. It was all working fine till last day. Now my app is not able to connect to hostinger i have contacted hostinger support center and they said me to buy a new domain.

[image]

Till last day i was not getting this `Your domain is not pointing to our name servers.`
and now my logcat of android studio is saying:

```
11-13 18:51:16.635 29958-30309/test.gul.newelectro1 E/Volley: [3245] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 503 for http://iot2k19.hostingerapp.com/do_login.php
```

this all was working fine and i didn't made any change so is it hostinger fault or i'm doing some mistake, because hostinger support center said to me that they are facing some issue regarding free subdomains and they are trying to solve it. But it's been a day and i'm getting this thing.
If we look to app it's saying :

[image]

These are are my API's(php files), my app is not able to access these files:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine,The error `503` your'e getting is the server telling you a service is currently unavailable,Hostinger free servers go down from time to time,shouldn't last more than a week so be patient it'll be back eventually,or else you can buy and pay for a domain if you need it available all the time. I tried your link just now and seems fine

Comment: That's i'm not getting, if i try to access my domain it's perfectly fine but as i mention above i have an android app and i have put my all API's(php files) on hostiger. and my app is not able to access those API's. it giving server error

Comment: so you tried just now and still get same volley error?

Comment: Strange,i think Volley may have cached response,delete the app reinstall then run it again

Comment: Tried but still same.

Comment: I think the culprit is the cloudflare protection, which shows you a "please wait" page when you try accessing a php page on hostinger using a browser, but which results in "503 error" when an app or script tries accessing the php file. I don't know how to solve this issue, but it is very annoying, because when I used free service 000webhost, I was able to call php scripts from inside php scripts; now I paid to switch to hostinger... and I lost this capability! There is a tutorial on Hostinger about how to enable an error log for 503 error, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: nothing, the tutorial is only about 503 errors raised by wordpress installed in hostinger, it does not help at all.